# Why using createElement value doesn't show my input element properly?

Tags: php, dom

I've the following code:

```
$newDOM = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$foo = $newDOM->createElement('Input', 'THIS IS MY VALUE');
$newDOM->appendChild($foo);
echo $newDOM->saveHTML();
```

This is what is outputted only:  `<Input>`

But when I change the createElement to a 'div'  it works okay

This is what is outputted with 'div' or any other input:

```
 <div>THIS IS MY VALUE</div>
```

This is my `var_dump($foo)`:

```
object(DOMElement)#5 (17) {
  ["tagName"]=>
  string(5) "Input"
  ["schemaTypeInfo"]=>
  NULL
  ["nodeName"]=>
  string(5) "Input"
  ["nodeValue"]=>
  string(16) "THIS IS MY VALUE"
  ["nodeType"]=>
  int(1)

  ["parentNode"]=>
  string(22) "(object value omitted)"
  ["childNodes"]=>
  string(22) "(object value omitted)"
  ["firstChild"]=>
  string(22) "(object value omitted)"
  ["lastChild"]=>
  string(22) "(object value omitted)"
  ["previousSibling"]=>
  NULL
  ["attributes"]=>
  string(22) "(object value omitted)"
  ["ownerDocument"]=>
  string(22) "(object value omitted)"
  ["namespaceURI"]=>
  NULL
  ["prefix"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["localName"]=>
  string(5) "Input"
  ["baseURI"]=>
  NULL
  ["textContent"]=>
  string(16) "THIS IS MY VALUE"
}
```

Comment: <input> is the only thing that shows

Comment: <div>THIS IS MY VALUE</div> shows when i use a DIV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument to `createElement` is the content of the tag you're creating. `<input>` tags can't contain text. You need to set its `value` attribute. You're trying to produce `<input value="this is my value">`, not `<input>this is my value</input>`.

See [`createAttribute`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createattribute.php).

Comment: Please give the OP an example to improve your post.

Comment: Also::: This does work when i echo it or place it in a variable... but i can i echo it right by the radio Button...                                                         The value of the element. By default, an empty element will be created. The value can also be set later with DOMElement::$nodeValue.